# Swift 3.0 Using a Table View to Show and Add Comments

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, custom-cell

I am interested in having a tableview for comments (something similar to instagram comments). So far, I have used a custom cell to set up a textView for comments in my set array, dataName. I was wondering how I could go about setting up a textfield and button on the last row of the tableview that would act as the place to input more comments. Do I need to create another customcell for this and implement this in cellForRowAt indexPath ?

```
var comments = ["I like this item","Where did you get this?", "I can't believe you found this!", "Hello", "Yay"]  

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    cell.commentView.text = dataName[indexPath.row]
    cell.commentView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.commentView.isEditable = false
    cell.commentView.isScrollEnabled = false


    return cell
}
```

Comment: @matt I am just having trouble understanding how to add different types of cells to the tableview. And to have the ability to say I want a specific cell on a certain row

Comment: OK that's a good answer. Well, just have two cell prototypes with two different identifiers. If you're on the last row, ask for the "comment" cell prototype in your `dequeue` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish you desired effect by adding a view that contains a text field and a button as the footer view of the tableview. And when a new comment is added you will proceed to add the comment to the array, and reload the tableview or insertRow with animation.

Comment: I've implemented what you suggested. When I add more rows, the tableview remains fixed viewing the first few rows (and I would have to scroll down to comment again). Is there a way I can have it such that after adding many rows, the tableview is always fixed on this footerview (and I would have to scroll up to view previous comments?)

Comment: Yes it is possible to have a floating footerview

Answer (score 0):

You already have one cell prototype called `"Cell"`. Just add another cell prototype called `"Comment"`. Now you have two cell prototypes with two different identifiers. If you're on the last row, ask for the `"Comment"` cell prototype in your `dequeue` call.